# Run a command only if the previous command was successful in Fish (like && in bash)

Tags: fish

Using Bash I've often done things like `cd /study && ls -la`
I understand that the double ampersand is telling the terminal don't execute part two of this command unless part one completes without errors.

My question is, Having just moved to the Fish shell and trying the same command I get an error stating I can't use `&&` and instructing me to use a single `&` which I believe backgrounds the task which isn't what I want.

Can anyone tell me the correct syntax to run my old Bash command in the Fish shell?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Instead of `&&`, which doesn't exist in `fish`, use `;` and the command [`and`](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#and):

```
cd /study; and ls -la
```

According to [the `fish` tutorial](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_combiners):

> Unlike other shells, `fish` does not have special syntax like `&&` or `||` to combine commands. Instead it has commands `and`, `or`, and `not`.