# Why does the command not exit smoothly?

Tags: fish

Following on from my previous [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261152/run-a-command-only-if-the-previous-command-was-successful-in-fish-like-in-ba) I tried to run `ls -l; and grep html;` which did what I wanted however the command didn't exit back to the prompt. Instead it appeared to be waiting for something else to happen and I had to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to end the process.

Can anyone explain why this happened and what the correct syntax for my command would be?

What I'm trying to do is have grep filter the output of the `ls -l`

Comment: What were you trying to do?

Comment: really what you should do is `ls -l *html*`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably wanted to pipe `ls -l` into `grep`, for which [fish uses a pipe character](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#piping) the same as other shells (for once):

```
ls -l | grep html
```

This is the same thing you would have written in Bash. Otherwise, `grep` is filtering your input from the terminal instead.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you didn't give `grep` a filename. syntax to use `grep` should be:

```
grep PATTERN [file]
```

if you don't give it a `file`, it waits for your input .